# Default value of a form in Django using REMOTE_USER

Tags: python, django, forms

I simply want the default value of an input field in a form to be equal to the value stored within the REMOTE_USER variable passed as a server variable. In the views.py file I can access this server variable via `request.META['REMOTE_USER']`.

In forms.py however I don't have the request data, so how can I set the value to this?

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class TimeSearchForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username:', max_length=10, min_length=3)
```

views.py form declaration:

```
form = TimeSearchForm(request.POST or None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can access the value in the view, that is where you should be setting the default value. You use the `initial` parameter to pass initial values to a form when you instantiate it.

```
form = TimeSearchForm(initial={'username': request.META['REMOTE_USER']})
```

**Edit**

Don't do it like that anyway, that's a fragile hack. Use the proper if/else:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TimeSearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ... whatever ...
else:
    form = TimeSearchForm(initial={'username': request.META['REMOTE_USER']})
return ...
```

Comment: I added how I declare my form into the OP. How should I be combining this with my already present declaration that includes sending post data if there is any?